# Building a reservation system

Tags: database-design

I am starting a new project on which I am making a reservation system as a PHP/ MySQL web application.

Basic functionality should be:
**admin** can add default appointments (several pro day)
**users** can attend the appointments (with a by admin set max).

Currently I'm figuring out how to make the database structure.

I was thinking of making two calendar databases:

```
default_calendar
- description
- day_of_week
- time_start
- time_end
- spots

extra_calendar
- description
- date_start
- date_end
- time_start
- time_end
- spots
- status  (1: available | 0: not available)
```

This is pretty straightforward and doable.

My challenge is to register the appointments.

Two solutions came to thought:

**One table**

Make one table with the reservations:

```
reservations
- id
- name
- date
- time_start
- time_end
- status (1: paid | 0: not paid)
```

**Or two tables**

One for the event
One for the reservations

```
event
- event_id
- date
- time_start
- time_end
- number_attending

reservation
- res_id
- event_id
- name
- status (1: paid | 0: not paid)
```

The advantage of the first solution is that only one table is needed. Plus when reservations are cancelled, it is easier to process

Advantage of solution two is that the query handling is easier, while for every event there is a single database record.

What do you suggest, or do you have a even better idea?

Comment: Questions asking for assistance in explaining, writing or debugging code are off-topic here.

Comment: I don't need explaining, writing or debugging, I would like some brainstorming about how to proceed with this :)

Comment: Define event vs. registration in the context of your app. Is it one event can have many registrations?

Comment: Yes, the admin can define how many participants can register to the event. So one event can have multiple registrations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1 violates [NF1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

That means the name of the event will be repeated in every reservation (data redundancy), and allowing for update anomalies and insertion anomalies.

That means that it would be possible to change the name or the event for reservations that belong to the same event ID. Or do the same when inserting. That also means that users would probably have to type the name of the event themselves instead of selecting from a list, since there is no list of events. You will end up with reservations for "Charity Concert", "charity concert", "Hcarity concert", "CHARITY CONCERT" etc., all refering to the same event.

- Option 1 is a no-go.
- Option 2 is the way to go.